# wsgi:warn between apache and python

Tags: python, django, apache

I ran a `django` project by `apache` but got

```
Internal Server Error
```

So i checked `error.log` and got:

```
[wsgi:warn] Target WSGI script '/var/www/shop/shop/wsgi.py'
  cannot be loaded as Python module.
```

I tried to fix this by 3 steps:

1. `sudo apt-get remove libapache2-mod-wsgi`
2. `pip install mod_wsgi`
3. `mod_wsgi-express module-config`

but i don't know how to add the information of config to `Apache` configuration.

I was using `Ubuntu`, so there is no file named `httpd.conf` in `Apache`, so I tried to insert the information of `mod_wsgi config` into the file `000-default`, but it didn't work and returned an error when I restarted `apache`:

```
caught sigterm shutting down
```

I tried to remove the code that i added and restart again,
but i got an other error:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process
  exited with error code.
```

I'm so confused, may somebody save me from the mess?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50165201/apache2-error-log-call-to-site-addsitedir-failed-for-null-stopping), it's work for me:
change the WSGIDaemonProcess like this:

```
myproject python-home=/home/ubuntu/Django/myvenv python-path=/home/ubuntu/Django/myproject
```